# How to associate an object to its shadow in Pygame?

Tags: python, oop, pygame, surface

I have a cloud class and I have a variety of cloud shapes so I need to associate each variation to its corresponding shadow in order to display it underneath it.

But I tried creating a dictionary with the clouds' images as keys and their shadows as values, I also created to have the clouds and shadows each in a separate list and then used the `for` loop to iterate over them and associate them but none of that worked.

I was facing an error which said `TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not iterable`

```
class Cloud(object):
    def __init__(self:
        imgs = random.choice([pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud1.png').convert_alpha(), pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud2.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud3.png').convert_alpha()])
        shadows = [pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\cloud_shadow.png').convert_alpha(), pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud2shadow.png').convert_alpha(), 
        pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud3shadow.png').convert_alpha()]
        self.x = random.randrange(-1500, -500)
        self.y = random.randrange(-100, 400)
        for img in imgs:
            for shadow in shadows:
                i = random.randrange(len(imgs))
                self.img = random.choice(self.imgs[i])
                self.shadow = self.shadow[i]
```

So what can i do instead ?

### NOTE :

I just need to associate the clouds' images to their shadows, but I know how to display each object along with its corresponding shadow.

Btw nevermind my messy file names ^^

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post some example code so we know what you're doing?

Comment: @AdamConrad Done

Comment: It looks like you are choosing a single image of the three that are loaded, which is why it complains about not being able to iterate. Also, because you are choosing it randomly, how do you know which shadow goes with the selected image?

Comment: @AdamConrad, the two lists are ordered in a way that the object with index 1 in the first list corresponds to the object with index 1 in the second one and so on.. Furthermore, i created instances of the cloud class so that each of them represents a randomly chosen cloud shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of clouds and a list of shadows:

```py
imgs = [pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud1.png').convert_alpha(),
   pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud2.png').convert_alpha(),
   pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud3.png').convert_alpha()]

shadows = [pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\cloud_shadow.png').convert_alpha(),
   pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud2shadow.png').convert_alpha(), 
   pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\testcloud3shadow.png').convert_alpha()]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists and choose a random element:

```py
self.img, self.shadow = random.choice(list(zip(imgs, shadows)))
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) takes two collections and merges them into a single collection, where each item is a tuple of an item from each collection.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I got an error in this line :  ``self.img, self.shadow = random.choice(zip(imgs, shadows))`` and i realized that it should be : ``self.img, self.shadow = random.choicel(list(zip(imgs, shadows)))``

Comment: @Developeeer Sorry, my bad: `self.img, self.shadow = random.choice(list(zip(imgs, shadows)))`